# SIGTERM cannot terminate a busy waiting process

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, atomic

I have a multi-threaded setup. One of the threads spins on a atomic <size_t> object, which is incremented by the other thread.

```
//global
atomic <size_t> var;

// in thread-1
while(var.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 0)
{
    //busy wait
}
// do something ...
```

I have observed that if the other thread is finished without incrementing `var`, the process cannot be killed using `ctrl+c` or using SIGTERM in htop.
I have to use SIGKILL for it. Any reason why is it so?

Comment: That doesn't sound normal; post a [mcve] of a whole program that gets into that state on your machine.  Did you use `pthread_exit()` to exit the main thread, or is it still running?  There's nothing special about busy-waiting on an atomic variable vs. a regular infinite loop, it's just executing a load instruction and compare/branch.

Comment: We would also need to know what platform you are running this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was a bug from my side. SIGTERM indeed works as expected.

A signal handler existed which stops processing of further events. But the current event which was busy in the while loop does not end and hence the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).